# Mysterious bug causes app to behave differently after it occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I have a custom range slider in my React APP. After interacting with it over and over again it will eventually trigger this message in the console. Afterwards, the slider behaves differently.

Sorry if the problem is vague. But I don't much of a clue as to what could be the cause.

Edited:

I finally found what triggers the bug. It is the Tooltip from material UI. Whenever I hover of the element that is wrapped inside of the tooltip, this warning appears.

however, still no clue where it would cause the range slider to be behave differently.

Comment: @Spectric I simply have no clue which parts would be the minimally reproducible example. The entire file is over 1000 lines long.

Comment: If you have no clue, neither do we.

Comment: @IanKemp, I have made an edit. I have identified the cause, but still not sure why it would have the side effect though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your error, it seems like a material ui issue (as you confirmed in your edit). material ui uses findDomNode, but react isn't happy with it. It's been a known issue for a while (you can see [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13221) & [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13394)). they [claim](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13394#issuecomment-900083405) it's resolved in v5 so migration to v5 would resolve the warnings.

Still you shouldn't see any change in behaviour though, unless you are doing something wrong, which wouldn't be possible to identify, unless you share your code where you use the Tooltip component.